# Getting Scalatron to Work (trouble with opcode)

Tags: scala, bots, opcode

I am new to Scala. I recently downloaded Scalatron in order to learn Scala. I already have the Scala plug-in for IntelliJ, so I figured the easiest option for setting up Scalatron would be to create the bot in IntelliJ, and add a ScalatronBot.jar to the Scalatron plugin directory. I started working my way through the basic examples in the Scalatron tutorial when I began to have problems. The following basic code works fine for my bot:

```
class ControlFunctionFactory { def create = new ControlFunction().respond _ }

class ControlFunction { def respond(input: String) = "Status(text=Hello World)" }
```

but something goes wrong when I try to access the input string, or 'opcode', from the server; the following does not work for me:

```
 class ControlFunctionFactory { def create = new ControlFunction().respond _ }
 class ControlFunction {
      def respond(input: String) = {
          val tokens = input.split('(')   
          if(tokens(0)=="React") {        
              "Move(direction=1:0)"       
          } 
          else { "" }
      }
  }
```

Instead, my bot appears, stuck in place, with the text 'disabled' next to it. I used Scalatron's online compiler and "sandbox run" with this code and it ran just fine. It's strange to me that I can get the basic "Hello World" bot to run just fine, but not this bot which utilizes the opcode. I am using Windows 7 and Google Chrome if that is relevant. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you provided unfortunately I cannot yet reproduce the problem. The code, as you state, works fine when compiled from the browser-based editor. For the moment I only have the following recommendations to try to resolve the problem:

- launch the Scalatron server from the command line. This will allow you to see its log messages on the console, which may provide information about why the plug-in was disabled by the server (generally because there was a problem communicating with it, an invalid response, or a security violation). You could check the "Scalatron Server Setup" documentation for additional command line options, such as `-verbose yes`
- retrace the setup steps for your IntelliJ Scalatron Bot project in the "Scalatron Player Setup" documentation: are you compiling into the correct directory? Anything missing?

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I did command line with the verbose option and it seems to find my plugin successfully; but then it gives the following error: error: exception while instantiating control function of plugin 'Sam': java.lang
.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/St
ring;

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are some incompatibilities with some versions of Scala compiler and Scalatron. I was getting the same error with Scala compiler 2.10.3. After downgrading to 2.9.2 everything started running just fine.

Unfortunately, I have no information what are the versions of Scala compiler compatible with Scalatron. I can only say that 2.9.2 works for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it took downgrading Scala from 2.11.4 to 2.9.2 and setting IntelliJ's Java SDK to the same I used to run the Scalatron server. Also IntelliJ updated itself and Scala plugin from 1.1.2 to 1.2.1 in the meantime (not sure if relevant)

At first it did not seem to help but then I tried to edit code via Web UI and successfully ran from there. After that, code edited and built in IntelliJ started to work too (after of course getting rid of such a stupid attempt as "Status(text"+input+")" ;)