# How to make IntelliJ scala project use Scala 2.9.2 version?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jar

I'm trying to create jar file from scala file - which will be used for Scalatron bot (http://scalatron.github.io/)

The problem is that if I create jar file using new scala versions 2.10 - 2.13 (these are the only one's that InteliJJ allows me to use) scalatron bot doesn't work.
However I found out that downgrading to scala 2.9.2 fixes the problem ([Getting Scalatron to Work (trouble with opcode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267847/getting-scalatron-to-work-trouble-with-opcode)).

How to downgrade to 2.9.2 on Intellij?

Comment: You probably can't. That is just too old. You would probably need to downgrade IntelliJ itself to do that. Just build your jar with SBT maybe... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SBT` is fully integrated with `IntelliJ Idea`, so you can create a `SBT` project in `IntlliJ` and make up the **build.sbt** file by yourself and put in it the `scala` version you want, compile, package and execute with `SBT`

```
name := "scalatron"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP3" % Test
```